# Exchange 2003 - is mixed authentication possible (user/pwd & whitelist IP)?

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2003

I am working with a client who has user/password authentication in place for their Exchange 2003 server. However, the application I am assisting them with will be running on a server inside their network, and is having trouble with user/password credentials.

Is it possible for the Exchange administrator to whitelist my application server's IP address so that my application will be able to send mail without any credentials at all? (I only need SMTP outbound mail, the application does not receive email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what internal relaying is for.

See here for setup pics: https://www.quantumsoftware.com.au/Support/KB/Article.aspx?KBArticleID=50

Just add that internal IP address to allow to relay email.